# параметры компонентов вне react-router-dom 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

В `react-router-dom v6` удалён *HOC* `withRouter`
А хук `useParams` при использовании вне `Routes` не возвращает параметры

Вопрос в следующем:
Посоветуйте как в коде ниже использовать параметры
(без костылей)

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Sidebar />
      <Content>
        <Router />
      </Content>
    </div>
  )
}

function Router() {
  return (
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<pages.Main />} />
        <Route path="/students" element={<pages.Students />} />
        <Route path="/personal" element={<pages.Personal />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Здесь, по задумке, `Header` и `Sidebar` находятся на странице всегда, при любом роуте
Но так как они находятся вне `Routes` не могу достать параметры через `useParams`

П.С. - Если добавить хедер и сайдбар внутрь `Routes`, приложение ломается с ошибкой:
`Uncaught Error: [Header] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`

Comment: А можете подсказать, как вы делаете такое название компонента `<pages.Main />`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Допустим у вас есть папка ```pages``` и в ней файлы ```main```,```profile``` и тд. И так же в папке ```pages``` есть файл ```index.js```. В нём вы экспортируете все компоненты этой папки ```export { default as Profile } from './profile'``` и  ```export { default as Main} from './main'``` и тд.  А далее там где хотите импортировать, импортируете всё под тем именем каким хотите ```import * as pages from '@pages'```

Comment: @OliverPatterson можете ознакомиться с этой ссылкой https://javascript.info/import-export#export-as и вот этой https://javascript.info/import-export#import-as

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение своего вопроса здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159726/making-sidebar-available-for-all-components-react-js-react-router-v6

Помогло использование компонента `Outlet` из `react-router-dom`

```
function PageLayout() (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Sidebar />
    <div className="page-container">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </div>
)

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router />
    </div>
  )
}

function Router() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<PageLayout />} >
        <Route path="/" element={<pages.Main />} />
        <Route path="/students" element={<pages.Students />} />
        <Route path="/personal" element={<pages.Personal />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```